# Can someone explain me why is that the output, C++ recursive function

Tags: c++, recursion, output

I don't understand why after running this code

```
int n;
int f(int x) 
{ 
    int n; 
    if (x > 0) 
    {
        if (x % 2 == 0) 
        {
            cout << x % 10;
            n = 1 + f(x / 10); 
        } 
        else 
        {
            n = 1 + f(x / 10);
            cout << x % 10; 
        }
        return n; 
    } 
    else return 0;
}

int main()
{
    cout << ' ' << f(8174);
    return 0;
}
```

I get `4817 4` instead of  `48174`

I need more words but i dont know what to say:))

Comment: I [can't reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/1KKde4) the error. I'm not getting a space in the output.

Comment: How you get `4817 4` ? what is your compiler/compiler options ?

Comment: i tried the on https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler and the output is "4817 4". I am using vs on my pc

Comment: its the same code here https://onlinegdb.com/BJVjUk93P but 4817 4 output

Comment: I have some certificate problem so I can't reach that site. It seems Yksisarvinen figured it out though. :-) Good catch!

Comment: Yes, in online gdb, with language set to `C++` or `C++14` gives the answer your describe. With `C++17` there's no space. You can add this information to your question if you want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Before C++17 order of argument evaluation is unspecified. This means compiler can either run `f(8174)` (and therefore all of its `std::cout << ...` statements) before `std::cout << ' '` or after that.

The fix is rather simple, you need to split your cout into two statements:

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << ' ';
    std::cout << f(8174)
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The order of evaluation of arguments is still unspecified in C++17. What changed, though, was the order of evaluation in a shift operator expression.